# onclicklistener not doing anything in code, no errors in logcat

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have the damnest problem. i have created an onclick listener in my activity. It is suppose to delete a listview item from my listview. But it does nothing when clicked. The app runs with no errors in logcat. its like the onclicklistener is not even in the code.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyEvents extends ActionBarActivity{

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myevents);

    //TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
    ListView dbListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myEventsListView);
    final SQLiteAdapter info = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    //long lg = 1;
    final Cursor myCursor;
    info.open();
    myCursor = info.getAllItems();
    startManagingCursor(myCursor);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MyEvents.this,
            R.layout.single_myevent, myCursor, new String[] { "title", "description", "time", "_id" }, new int[] { R.id.myEventstitle, R.id.myEventsDesc, R.id.myEventsTime, R.id.myeventid }, 0);
dbListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    info.close();
    dbListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String eventid = (String)view.findViewById(R.id.myeventid).toString();
        long myrow = Long.parseLong(eventid);
        Log.d("onclick", "clicked " + eventid);
        //SQLiteAdapter sqlAd = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        info.open();
        info.deleteEntry(myrow);
        Toast.makeText(MyEvents.this, "deleted" + eventid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        info.close();
        Intent restarteventpage = new Intent(MyEvents.this, MyEvents.class);
        startActivity(restarteventpage);
    }

});
}
}
```

---

The answer was like  'rIHaN JiTHiN' said in the comments above. I had a button and some textviews in my single row xml. once I deleted the button I could click the row. But how do I prevent this? I had future plans for that button.

But now I recieve errors in logcat when I click a row , it says :

```
Numberformatexception: Invalid long: "android.widget.TextView...app:id/eventid long.invalidlong
```

But I need this textview, it stores the id of the row which I am using to identify the row so I can delete it from my sqlite database. am I writting this code wrong? or is there another way?

Comment: Toast don't show either. I'm beginning to think its eclipse that's coursing this. Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Did you checked the onItemClick method via debugging? And Make sure that the method is calling or not.

Comment: Ok i'm not that fluent with the debugger, but i just ran it anyway to see if anything would happen when i click. nothing happened. i put the breakpoint at 'dbListView.setOnItemClickListener' its really like the SDK is not seeing this code.

Comment: Is there any `Buttons` or other `Views` in your list item that could consume the click event?

Comment: set every element in the row layout that you are using to focusable false and focusableInTouchMode to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my Invalid long problem :

instead of just doing this :

```
String eventid = (String)view.findViewById(R.id.myeventid).toString();
    long myrow = Long.parseLong(eventid);
```

I added the Textview first, then get the text into a string:

```
TextView eventid = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myeventid);
        String stringeventid = eventid.getText().toString();
        long myrow = Long.parseLong(stringeventid);
```

Oh boy im really getting good at this! :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you try moving `dbListView.setAdapter(adapter);` below your `dbListView.setOnItemClickListener();` ?

Comment: after relocating dbListView.setOnItemClickListener(), it now crashes everytime i try to run my activity. logcat says : Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.